# CF-CustomBuildpacksDisabled(290004): Custom buildpacks are disabled

Tags: jenkins, cloud-foundry

`$ cd ${WORKSPACE}`

`$ cf push -f manifest.yml`

Below is the error from PCF after running above commands in jenkins:

```
org.cloudfoundry.client.v2.ClientV2Exception: CF-CustomBuildpacksDisabled(290004): Custom buildpacks are disabled
```

where `manifest.yml` is as shown below:

```
---
applications:
- name: xyz-app-frontend
  memory: 64M
  disk_quota: 64M
  instances: 1
  random-route: true
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/anc-buildpack.git#v1.0.1
```

---

```
J:\>cf buildpacks | findstr nginx
nginx-buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v1-0-7   21         true      false    nginx-buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v1.0.7.zip                cflinuxfs3
```

1)
Is this error related to `buildpack` entry in manifest.yml?

2)
If yes, How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is this error related to buildpack entry in manifest.yml?

Yes.

> 2) If yes, How to resolve this error?

You have two options:

1.) Remove that line from your manifest.yml and use a buildpack that's included by default on your platform (i.e. see output of `cf buildpacks`).

2a.) Talk to your platform operator and ask them to allow you to run custom buildpacks. There is a setting which disables running custom buildpacks. I believe this is global for all custom buildpacks across all users on the foundation.

2b.) If you can't allow all custom buildpacks, you can ask your operator to deploy a buildpack for you. They can take the buildpack you're using, package it up & run `cf create-buildpack` to add it to the list of buildpacks on your platform.

Hope that helps!